# Add JScrollPane to JFrame

Tags: java, jframe, scrollbar

Working on my final class project and am hoping I can add a scroll bar to my JFrame when it's needed.

I'd like for it to appear only when the JButtons start to disappear on the JFrame, but I need a working scroll bar, of any kind, first. Any help is appreciated.

**Here is the code I have so far for the GUI constructor:**

```
public GUI() 
{

    JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    initComponents();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setResizable(true);
    this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
    {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent evt)
            {
                posX=evt.getX();
                posY=evt.getY();
            }
    });
    this.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter()
    {
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent evt)
            {           
                setLocation (evt.getXOnScreen()-posX,evt.getYOnScreen()-posY);
            }
    });
}
```

**AND the main:**

```
public static void main(String args[]) 
{

    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
    {
        public void run()
        {
            new GUI().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

I'm at a loss. I've read the scroll pane tutorials from Oracle with little success.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where is content added to the JScrollPane, and where is the JScrollPane added to the UI?

Comment: I guess I need to somehow add all the components from initComponents() to the scroll pane. How do I do that

Comment: `How do I do that` I don't know what `initComponents`, so cannot comment specifically but I presume there is a main JPanel in there that you can add to the JScrollPane. Also see answer by @Farrukh

Comment: initComponent() is the void method NetBeans automatically creates to add buttons, labels, etc.

Comment: `NetBeans automatically creates to add buttons, labels, etc` If you are new to Swing, I'd recommend learning how to construct a UI by hand. You should be able to adapt what @Farrukh has given into the initComponents method. As is without seeing more code it is hard to give a specific answer

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a new control panel object
2. Add panel to the container
3. Add JScrollpane to Frame

For example:

```
JPanel contain = new JPanel();
container.add(panel1);
JScrollPane obj = new JScrollPane(contain);
frame.add(obj);
```

Hope this will help regarding JScrollPane